# FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x<sanitized>)

Tags: android, visualizer

I am using Visualizer class for music beats change that gives me value which I am using to show spectrum animation user experience as:

```
  visualizer = Visualizer(audioSessionId)
        visualizer!!.enabled = false
        visualizer!!.captureSize = Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]
        visualizer!!.setDataCaptureListener(object : Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener {
            override fun onWaveFormDataCapture(
                visualizer: Visualizer, bytes: ByteArray,
                samplingRate: Int
            ) {
                val number = 128 - (if (bytes[0] < 0) -bytes[0] else bytes[0]).toInt()
                val result = (number.toFloat() / 128) * 100

                volumeBoosterFragment?.binding!!.animSeekbar.setProgress((100f - result))
                volumeBoosterFragment?.binding!!.animSeekbar2.setProgress((100f - result))

                equalizerFragment?.binding!!.animSeekbar.setProgress((100f - result))
                equalizerFragment?.binding!!.animSeekbar2.setProgress((100f - result))
            }

            override fun onFftDataCapture(
                visualizer: Visualizer, bytes: ByteArray,
                samplingRate: Int
            ) {
            }
        }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false)
```

But i am facing a crash repeatedly on developer console and i cant find out why?

[libc.so] abort
Hide crash
SIGABRT
Sample attributes:
Condor Griffe_T9_Plus (Griffe T9 Plus)
Android 9 (SDK 28)
Version: 9 (1.9)
Occurred: 2 hours ago
Thread
FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x)

---

pid: 0, tid: 10734 >>> <<<

backtrace:
#00  pc 0x0000000000021c24  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
#01  pc 0x000000000008304c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__fortify_fatal(char const*, ...)+120)
#02  pc 0x0000000000082748  /system/lib64/libc.so (HandleUsingDestroyedMutex(pthread_mutex_t*, char const*)+52)
#03  pc 0x00000000000825fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+228)
#04  pc 0x00000000000a8cd4  /system/lib64/libmedia.so (android::Visualizer::periodicCapture()+56)
#05  pc 0x00000000000a8b2c  /system/lib64/libmedia.so (android::Visualizer::CaptureThread::threadLoop()+88)
#06  pc 0x000000000000fb48  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
#07  pc 0x00000000000b4f38  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
#08  pc 0x0000000000081a80  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
#09  pc 0x0000000000023478  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)

From my native android VolumeBooster Application Crash reporting at developer Console but not on Firebase Crashlytics
My assupmtion about this crash is because of android.media.audiofx.virtualizer Class.
Please suggest me the crash solution